# The Tall Tale of Terminating Transfinite Towers

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, automorphism-groups

The transfinite *tower* of iterative automorphisms of a group $G$ is simply definied to be the following chain of the groups where $G_{\alpha+1}=Aut(G_{\alpha})$ for each ordinal $\alpha$ and the direct limit is taken at the limit stages:

$G\rightarrow Aut(G)\rightarrow Aut(Aut(G))\rightarrow\cdots\rightarrow G_{\alpha}\rightarrow G_{\alpha+1}\rightarrow\cdots$

The tower *terminates* when a fixed point is reached, namely one of the groups in the chain is isomorphic to its automorphism group by the natural map. Simon Thomas has proved that the automorphism tower of every centerless group eventually terminates. Later, Hamkins completed Thomas' result by showing that the automorphism tower terminates for every group:

- *Thomas, Simon*, [**The automorphism tower problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2044505), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 95, 166-168 (1985). [ZBL0575.20030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0575.20030).
- *Hamkins, Joel David*, [**Every group has a terminating transfinite automorphism tower**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-98-04797-2), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 126, No. 11, 3223-3226 (1998). [ZBL0904.20027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0904.20027).

Hamkins' theorem gives a sense to the natural definition of the notion of **terminating number** of a group, $\tau(G)$, that is the least ordinal where the automorphism tower of $G$ terminates.

My first question is about the minimum power of $ZFC$ that is needed to carry out Thomas-Hamkins' proof:

> **Question 1.** How much $ZFC$ is needed to prove that the automorphism tower terminates for every group, $G$, and so $\tau(G)$ is well-defined? Particularly, is $AC$ used anywhere in Hamkins or Thomas' results (which Hamkins' proof is partially based on)? If so, is this use of $AC$ essential? If yes, are the following two statements equivalent?
>
> - The automorphism tower terminates for every group.
> - The Axiom of Choice.

My next question is about the relation between the terminating number of the direct product of two groups and the terminating number of each component:

> **Question 2.** What is the relation between $\tau (G\times H)$ and $\tau (G)$, $\tau(H)$? Is there an upper bound for $\tau (G\times H)$ expressible in terms of $\tau (G)$, $\tau(H)$? For instance, is it true to say $\tau (G\times H)\leq Max (\tau (G), \tau(H))$ or $\tau (G)+\tau(H)$ or $\tau (G).\tau(H)$ ...?

The "Max" bound in the above question is inspired by the fact that for finite groups, $G, H$, whose orders are relatively prime, we have $Aut(G\times H)\cong Aut(G)\times Aut(H)$. If one somehow manages to keep this pattern through the entire chain then the automorphism tower of $G\times H$ terminates after $Max (\tau (G), \tau(H))$ steps.

In particular, computing $\tau(G^n)$ (and comparing it with $\tau(G)$) could be of interest as well. For instance, in the special case that $G$ is a cyclic group of order $p$, one has $Aut(G^n)\cong GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and so $\tau (G^{n})=\tau (GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_p))+1$.

Comment: My proof that every group leads eventually to a centerless group uses the replacement axiom, since I use that every function from the ordinals to the ordinals has a closure point. I haven't ever thought much about whether the arguments use AC. Hmmm.

Comment: @Joel: Every function from $V$ to $V$ has a closure point, assuming Replacement.

Comment: Yes, of course, and both forms of closure are equivalent to replacement/collection over separation etc. My proof, however, used explicitly a certain function on the ordinals, the function mapping $\alpha$ to $\beta$, when all the group elements at stage $\alpha$ that will eventually die, die before $\beta$. Meanwhile, it seems that one will want at least power set to define the tower, since otherwise you can't seem to know that the automorphism group even exists as a set.

Comment: Any thoughts on the second question?

Comment: I don't expect any positive results of that nature, in light of the kind of thing happening in my joint paper with Simon: http://jdh.hamkins.org/changingheights/. The phenomenon is that when you make a change to the automorphism group, the tower can suddenly grow much much taller (or shorter). We used this to control the height of a tower of a fixed group by forcing, by adding generic outer automorphisms to the group.

Comment: For example, in the product case, sure, the product of the automorphism groups is sitting inside the automorphisms of the product, but there could be more, since the two factors could interact, and this might totally affect the nature of the next group in the tower, and therefore could cause huge changes in the height of the new tower.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, I am well aware of that paper (and also [your related work with Fuchs](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702768)) which reveals a high degree of sensitivity of the terminating number to forcing and set-theoretic assumptions. It is actually a very *malleable* mathematical object as you described. However, it seems at least in some special cases one may find explicit expressions describing $\tau (G\times H)$. e.g. For $G=H$, a cyclic group of prime order $p$, we have $Aut(G^2)\cong GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_p)$. So $\tau(G^2)=\tau(GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_p))+1$ and this holds in every model.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins A side remark on your joint paper with Simon: It seems your result is slightly weaker than saying *"The terminating number is forcing-sensitive"*. In fact, you have proved that it is possible (i.e. consistent) for the terminating number to be forcing sensitive in a suitable generic extension. Right? If so, was there any progress in the direction of obtaining a more direct result? I mean changing the terminating number from an arbitrary ground model. What about indestructibility results in the form of forcing terminating number to be unchangeable under certain forcing notions?

Comment: This is in part what Gunter Fuchs and I had done. In my argument with Simon, we had to force to create the group, but with Gunter, we proved that there is such a malleable group assuming only $\Diamond$.  We never got it purely in ZFC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a relevant paper,

> *Kaplan, Itay; Shelah, Saharon*, [**The automorphism tower of a centerless group without choice**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00153-009-0154-2), Arch. Math. Logic 48, No. 8, 799-815 (2009). [ZBL1192.03026](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1192.03026).

At least for a centerless group, it seems that every automorphism tower stabilizes below the Lindenbaum number of the power set of finite sequences of the group.

While I don't quite know how to move from a group to a centerless group without choice, let me point out that $G\mapsto\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is a function on the universe, and by replacement there is some $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha$ is a closure point of that function. I suspect that an argument would work in a choiceless setting from this point.

Comment: I think my proof does not use AC at all, and so from any group $G$ you get eventually (by the replacement axiom) a centerless group. So this seems to complete the proof in ZF.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Joel, doesn't your proof reduce the general case to the centerless case? If so, Simon's proof, as far as I know, uses AC.

Comment: @Burak: Have you read my answer and at least the abstract of the linked paper?

Comment: My theorem is that for any group $G$, the tower eventually has a centerless group, and this does not use AC. I am interpreting Asaf's answer here to say that Simon's theorem can be proved for centerless groups without AC.  In this case, the full termination theorem can be proved in ZF.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, the paper proves Simon's result without AC, so, this together with Joel's paper, which apparently not uses AC, answers the question. When I read Joel's comment, I mistakenly thought that Joel's 1998 proof of the full result did not use AC (since this paper of Shelah was written in 2009.) That's why I wanted to double check whether there was some way to avoid Simon's proof back then in Joel's 1998 paper.

Comment: @Burak: Ah, okay.

Comment: (+1) While it is rather hard to believe that Simon's seemingly strong result is provable merely using $ZF$ but let's trust Itay, Saharon, and the anonymous referees of their paper, and take this fact for granted. I am inclined to push the acceptance button for this answer (to the question 1) right now, but maybe it is better to wait a little bit to see whether anything shows up for the question 2. Anyway, thanks for the useful reference, Asaf!

Comment: You may also look at [Automorphism towers and definability in generalized Baire spaces](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/pluecke/pub/thesis.pdf) where details about the Kaplan-shelah's result and related theorems are proved.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Interesting thesis which partially serves as an expository paper on Kaplan-Shelah's result! Kheili Mamnun, Mohammad! :-)